# File Share directory on IIS Windows 10

Tags: symbolic-link, iis

I'm trying to set up just a simple directory on IIS, I used mklink -D on the command line to make a symlink called "fileshare" under wwwroot to a directory under my main user's Documents folder for hosting files.

I enable "Directory Browsing" on IIS though, and I still get a 401 error trying to browser the directory or download a file from that directory directly.

Answer (score 0):

As I was typing this question the answer came.

Make sure to set permissions on the directory under Documents that you symlinked to.

I set it to full control for "Everyone" in my case since it was just a simple anonymous file share, but set yours appropriately for your security.